# Insert figure in a multipanel plot using R

Tags: r, image, grimport

I need to insert 4 graphic pictures (.ps) into a multipanel (4 boxes) using R. Does anybody has a tip for it?

I have search a lot and I didn't find a solution. The way I'm trying now (but no success) is using screen:

```
m <- rbind(c(0.1, 0.55, 0.55, 1), c(0.55, 1, 0.55, 1),
+    c(0.1, 0.55, 0.1, 0.55), c(0.55, 1, 0.1, 0.55))
split.screen(m)

for(var in 1:4){
  screen(var)
  PostScriptTrace(paste("var",var,".ps",sep=""),paste("var",var,".xml",sep=""))
  Pic = readPicture(paste("var",var,"Dia",d,".xml",sep=""))
  par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  plot(1, axes = FALSE, type = "n",panel = function (x,y,...){grid.picture(Pic)}) 
   box()
} #end do loop for var 4:7
close.screen(all.screens = TRUE)
```

Comment: Why not just make a 2x2 multi-figure plot & output it as ps?